# Whenever I run any of React native apps it only showed "Something went wrong"

Tags: react-native, expo

When I installed React Native App by using Expo, I tried to run by `npx expo start` and scan the QR code by mobile phone Expo app. However, I could not figure out why all the time it only showed "Something went wrong". Are there any solutions that could fix the issue?

Even I searched some solutions from the Internet, I tried out to solve myself but still got stucked

Comment: hi, have you followed the official documentation? https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=quickstart

Have you looked at the github issues?

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

and the expo documentation: 

https://docs.expo.dev/

I hope this can help, in any case, it should be better if you share the entire error here, so someone ca helps.

Comment: Are you using iOS or androidd device?
Are the devices on the sam network?
Do you have a custom development client ?
Are you using the latest expo go app ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did follow thoroughly the setup documentation but however could not figure out where is the problem that something went wrong